# Firefox changing case of Request Header key?

Tags: firefox, httprequest, aws-api-gateway, mozilla

I have a JS code and a Server Endpoint(NodeJS AWS Lambda)
the 
Server API :

```
if(request.headers.specialKey === "SpecialKey") {
console.log("case sensitive")
} else {
console.log("lower case ")
}
```

for some reasons only for one specific customer we get this "SpecialKey"
and the same is maintained for Origin and Content-Type

Can someone tell who is doing this transformation?

Browser?  Network?   Gateway?

we are clueless and it happens only with one person 
and I understand that the header keys are case-insensitive 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

Comment: Ideally the client and server-side should check for the same keys and its better to have lower case keys to avoid any such issues, but the real question why and who does this conversion is not known

Comment: one reason I discovered is the use of proxy at the client side impacts the headers being sent